# Fabricjs - Get objects in group to be based on left wall

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yeftc60v/1/

So I'm trying to get the `obj.left` to be based on the left side(wall) of the group instead of the center. So right now, when I try to get the `left` of an object, if it's on the left side, it will return a negative number.

I've tried both `setOriginY` and `setOriginX` but they don't have any effect.

I'm working around this by doing some maths based on the group's width.

Right now if you hit the "clone" button, the left values read negative values (-100.5 and -0.5). Instead they should be 0 and 99.5(I think), respectively.

Comment: @ℊααnd So notice on my fiddle. If you select the group and hit clone. In the console, the left stats are -100.5 and -0.5. They should instead read 0 and 99.5(I think) respectively instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, any active group­*'s* origin `x` and `y` will always be at center. This won't take `originX` and `originY` property into consideration, hence setting `setOriginX` and `setOriginY` won't have any effect.

To get around this, you need to manually calculate the object­*'s* `top` and `left` position respective to the selected group, like so ...

```
let objLeft = obj.left + (active.width / 2);
let objTop = obj.top + (active.height / 2);
```

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
   left: 50,
   top: 50,
   fill: "#FF0000",
   stroke: "#000",
   width: 100,
   height: 100,
   strokeWidth: 1,
   opacity: .8
});
var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
   left: 150,
   top: 150,
   fill: "#FF0000",
   stroke: "#000",
   width: 100,
   height: 100,
   strokeWidth: 1,
   opacity: .8
});
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.add(rect1);

function clone() {
   let active = canvas.getActiveGroup();
   if (active) {
      active.forEachObject(obj => {
         let clone = obj.clone();
         
         // get object's left & top relative to the group
         let objLeft = obj.left + (active.width / 2);
         let objTop = obj.top + (active.height / 2);
         
         clone.setLeft(objLeft + active.left);
         clone.setTop(objTop + active.top);
         canvas.add(clone);
      });
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.11/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
<button onclick="clone()">
Clone
</button>
```

Comment: yeah I just used some maths instead. But thanks for searching